# Is there a way to avoid fees when moving funds from one wallet to another?

Tags: blockchain, ether, gas, wallets

We have a general question regarding gas fees and we would like to get a better understanding on how an Ethereum based gateway might work.

Let's take for example the implementation of Coinbase marketplace. Every time you are generating a new invoice, Coinbase allows you to pay it using a different Ethereum address. For example let's imagine that we have the following addresses:

- https://commerce.coinbase.com/invoices/E99MHH6Y
- https://commerce.coinbase.com/invoices/BWFG52TT
- https://commerce.coinbase.com/invoices/RQ73ND8N

In the end it allows you to withdraw the total of the amount using another wallet:

[image]

How do they avoid fees, if they do of course, while moving the funds from the addresses where the payment was done to the main wallet address?

According to https://github.com/btcpayserver/btcpayserver/pull/1730 what we describe was the reason that they "removed" the Ethereum support from BTCPayserver as well.

Is the only solution to just create a single wallet for each "merchant" instead?

Comment: Coinbase had a solution using smart contracts, see their blog https://blog.coinbase.com/usdc-payment-processing-in-coinbase-commerce-b1af1c82fb0, but that was 3 years ago.

Comment: thanks a lot @Ismael! We will take a look!

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to avoid fees on Ethereum or other similar forks.

The minimum transaction gas use is 21000, that's also the gas cost of a basic value transfer transaction.

That's also true for the London fork, taken from [Ethereum's blog](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/gas/#post-london) -

> Starting with the London network upgrade, every block has a base fee,
> the minimum price per unit of gas for inclusion in this block,
> calculated by the network based on demand for block space.